# Is it possible to convert a vector into a nested vector using a libc pointer?

Tags: c, rust, libc

I want to turn a vector (`Vec<u8>`) into a nested vector (`Vec<Vec<u8>>`), for example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6] -> [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

To do so, I don't want to use iterators, `collect` or `reduce`, I want to convert the `Vec` into a C pointer:

```
let ptr_vec = my_vec.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_void;
```

and then, convert this pseudo-`char *my_vec` into a pseudo-`char *my_vec[3]`, so I don't have to read through my entire vector.

Is this possible? If so, does it really increase performance on huge vectors?

Comment: transmute: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/casting-between-types.html#transmute

Comment: @sailfish009 it's pretty irresponsible to hand someone Rust's *single largest  footgun* with zero warning about using it. `transmute` is almost never the right tool for the job.

Comment: *I want to turn a vector (`Vec<u8>`) into a nested vector (`Vec<Vec<u8>>`)* — **why** do you want to do this? *I don't want to use iterators, `collect` or `reduce`* — **why** do you not want to use these? You mention performance, but you're not even sure that this transformation will help. Are you already familiar with of slices? You can just do `let a = &my_vec[0..3]` and you don't have to allocate anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you've said, I'm willing to bet that you don't really want a `Vec<Vec<u8>>`, but that you want a way to *index* your data as if it was a 2D rectangular matrix (i.e. a matrix where all rows have the same length). And I'm assuming that you don't want to write the actual formula (`row*stride+col`) each time. There is probably something on http://crates.io that would help, but if you want to do it yourself, you can wrap your `Vec<u8>` into a struct:

```
struct VecWrapper {
   stride: usize,
   data:   Vec<u8>,
}

impl VecWrapper {
   fn get (&self, row: usize, col: usize) -> u8 {
      self.data[row*self.stride + col]
   }
   fn set (&self, row: usize, col: usize, val: u8) {
      self.data[row*self.stride + col] = val;
   }
}
```

Or you can implement the `Index` and `IndexMut` traits to index through the `[]` operator (although you will need to use tuple indices, and using will look like `array[(row, col)]`)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible ?

No.  You *cannot* perform structural changes like that through pointer casting.  Calling `as_ptr` on a `Vec<u8>` will get you a pointer to the `Vec`'s elements of type `*const u8`.  Casting that to `*const *const [u8; 3]` makes no sense, because now you're trying to treat it as a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of `u8`.  In other words, you'd be interpreting the `u8`s *as* pointers to non-existent arrays.

Worse, even if this *did* work, if you converted this pointer back into `Vec<Vec<u8>>`, you'd crash the instant you started deallocating things, because you'd have split ownership of the *single* allocation of the original `Vec` between multiple `Vec`s.  This is a problem because you *can't* split ownership of an allocation; each `Vec` would be trying to deallocate the entire chunk of memory.

> To do so, I don't want to use Iterators, ...

I can't think of any reason *not* to use iterators for this, given that any valid solution to this problem is going to be equivalent to:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6];
    let vs = v.chunks(3).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", vs);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the enlightment, I didn't want to use iterators because if my Vector length is around 1 million, I'll have to iterate 1 million time to get the job done right ? Is there a way (for very large vector) to do it via the GPU ?

Comment: @boehm_s: You are asking how to transform the layout of the data.  There is *no way of doing this* that doesn't involve processing the entire thing.  A GPU cannot help you.  You cannot magically wave away the cost of doing this.  The only other alternative would be to wrap the `Vec<u8>` in a type that does the lookup on the fly (*i.e.* ask for element `i`, it returns `&[3*i..3*(i+1)]`).